# Do we need mod elections?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

My experience here is mainly due to my activity in Chess and Earth Science Stack Exchanges. While I see very active moderators in Chess Exchange: [Brian Towers](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/4418/brian-towers) and [Glorfindel](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/7297/glorfindel), I don't see the diamond so frequently in use in Earth Science. We have only two moderators, [gerrit](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/6/gerrit) and [hichris123](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/20/hichris123), and they are not as active as the chess site mods.

My intuition tells me that the reputed scientists on the site are not interested in helping with moderation too much, and that they do moderation tasks just because the site lacks necessary moderation. I say that after starting to close the [identify-my-rock](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-my-rock) questions. It took months to completely close and delete those questions while I am sure at chess Brian Towers or Glorfindel would have settled it in an afternoon. I feel it is unnecesary to disturb our valuable scientists answering questions asking them for intervention to close and reopen questions. At chess site Brian Towers is retired and allday joined and once a "duplicate" or a "needs clarification" or an "is off-topic" question appear it is automatically closed. If the poster edits his question and rep users ask to reopen it is Brian Towers himself who reopen the question using "his magic hammer"

I am sure some of our rep users visit the site daily and can help the site if we allow them to have access to moderation tools.

Should we have elections?

*I am expresing an opinion and I am not saying this to postulate myself, I cannot be moderator with my lack of english and my emotional ups and downs due to my menthal illness.

Comment: I'll leave it to someone on staff to announce timing (since I'm not 100% sure on the exact date), but an election is already planned for sometime in the next few months.

Comment: @hicris123 Ok thank you. Happy to read it. I think that would help you moderating the site. If you wish you can include the status-completed tag.

Comment: My mistake. I think I might have been in a time warp. I can recall seeing a diamond next to the name a while ago.

Comment: Do we actually need new or other moderators? My feeling is that there isn't a specific issue that requires changing how the moderation works in the site. It all looks ok to me.